# How to refresh Devexpress GridControl ItemsSource(as Datatable) in MVVM(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a GridControl(Devexpress v13) in view(WPF). A **Datatable** set values in ViewModel and assigned to ItemsSource. But ItemsSource filled only initialize. Later Datatable's value changes but it doesn't refresh.
How to ItemsSource refresh?

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="GridControlData" DataSource="{Binding DtCriterias, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" Width="400" Height="100">
```

I hope you know what I mean. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Property changed using:

```
 public DataTable DtCriterias {
            get { return _dtCriterias; }
            set
            {
                _dtCriterias = value;
                Notify(() => DtCriterias);
            }
        }

protected void Notify(Expression<Func<object>> expression)
        {

            if (_propertyChangedEvent == null) return;

            Notify(GetPropertyName(expression));
        }

protected void Notify(string propertyName)
        {
            if (_propertyChangedEvent != null)
            {
                _propertyChangedEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found reason of problem.
I am using encapsulation and I was set private value(_dtCriterias). Therefore Property Changed Event wasn't work.

Definitions:

```
private DataTable _dtCriterias;

public DataTable DtCriterias {
    get { return _dtCriterias; }
    set
    {
        _dtCriterias = value;
        Notify(() => DtCriterias);
    }
}
```

When I have problem datatable set:

```
_dtCriterias = GetValue().DefaultView.ToTable("FooTable");
```

Solution:

```
DtCriterias = GetValue().DefaultView.ToTable("FooTable");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ObservableCollection<ClientB2B> Clients
{
    get
    {
        return _clients;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_clients == value) return;
        _clients = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(); // This is what you need
    }
}
```

Implement this interface - INotifyPropertyChanged

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, e);
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: I am using Property Change Event but it doesn't refresh

Comment: It is not a problem. In my code change ObservableCollection to DataTable.

Comment: Notify("DtCriterias") - check this

Comment: I found reason of problem and I answered the question. Thank you for your advices @Bofort